Frozen os while using os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
File "C:\Users\dhruv\Desktop\langchain\app.py", line 9, in 
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]=os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "", line 690, in setitem
File "", line 750, in check_str
TypeError: str expected, not NoneType
how to resolve this error

Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide a minimal reproducible example.
P.S: Do you have your OPENAI_API_KEY?

Understanding the issue (Optional):
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]=os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY") 

The particular line of python code loads the variable - OPENAI_API_KEY from environmental variables. The error suggest that you have not yet set the local environmental variable.
Solution 1:

You can set up the api key using the export command in the command line or terminal.

$ export OPENAI_API_KEY='sk-your-api-key'

Solution 2:

Adding the api key to the .env file and loading using dotenv library

$ echo 'OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-your-api-key` >> .env

Install the library
$ pip install python-dotenv

Load the variable in the python code
import os

from dotenv import load_env


load_env()

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]=os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY") 


I was getting the same error even after implementing Mahimai Raja J's solution
import os
from dotenv import load_env
load_env()
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]=os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY") 

My friend noticed that in my .env file, there was an extra space after
OPENAI_API_KEY = "sk ***"

I instead needed to enter
OPENAI_API_KEY= "sk ***"

(notice the space is removed between OPENAI_API_KEY and the =)
I am new to software development and hence I didn't not know that a space would matter. This solved my issue. So how you enter your information into the .env file also matters.

This doesn't seem credible. Could you please validate your answer? Perhaps you could provide supporting evidence, such as putting the space back in and proving that it fails again.
